# Order a matrix of values based on gradient

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

The goal is to visualize a matrix of values 'nicely'. The matrix looks like

```
     a  b  c
 A   2  3  1
 B   5  6  7
 C   2  9  5
```

We've two sets {A} and {a}, that have no predefined order. We've also a measure value for each combination M(A,a) = Number.

We would like show the values in a 'nice' way by sorting these values for both sets. We want in the bottom left the smaller values and in the top right the biggest values.

So, for each Matrix of measures M we can define a function that is based on the gradient. For each possible order of set {A} and {a} we define the gradient as :

```
 Gradient(i,j) = F(M(i+1,j) - M(i,j)) + F(M(i,j+1) - M(i,j))

 where F(x) = x if x >0 and F(x) = 2*x if x < 0 as we want to go 'up'

 Gradient( M(A,a) ) - Sum( Gradient(i,j), for all i,j except the top and right border )
```

The 'nice' order is the one where we've (indeed not guarantee it's unique). The value of 2 in the F(x) function is arbitrary but the goal is to give more negative weight to the gradiants that go down. If somebody has a better idea welcomed.

```
 Max( Gradient )
```

Besides doing all combinations that is a terrible algorithm O(n^4), is there a better solution? Some formal ideas about this problem?

Comment: What is `Max ( Gradient )`? Do you mean to maximise `Sum(Gradient(i,j) for all i, j)`? NB: This will not ensure that the value in the bottom-left corner is great. What is the definition of `Gradient(i,j)` when `i,j` is a cell in the rightmost column and/or bottom row?

Comment: Sorry, the Gradient is the sum of all Gradients yes. The top and right border have no gradient

Comment: You mean the bottom row has no gradient, right? Or do you number the rows from bottom to top?

Comment: as you wish, bottom left was (0,0) for me. But that's easy to change.

Comment: The absolute values you take will allow a solution where the values not only go up (in the direction from bottom-left to top-right), but could "alternate" between small and greater values. This would not really be a gradient in the original sense of the word. Is that intended?

Comment: ups,yes it has to be a bit more complicated as we want to go up. It was a to quick fix as I without the function only the first and last value are taking into account. the value two is arbitrary

Comment: OK, so you want to give a kind of penalty when values go down.

Comment: Apologies as I can't quite understand why the factor of 2 is necessary; wouldn't there already be a penalty if the values were decreasing, as the contribution to `Gradient(i, j)` would be negative?

Comment: That was my first though, but without the factor we've then that Gradient is the difference between the last and the first value

Comment: That's what happens when you sum up the first `F`-terms; but the second `F` term does not cancel so trivially (difference to the next row) - so I wonder if that would still have the desired effect when acted over the entire matrix. (Apologies as I don't know how to express this very succinctly)

Comment: I see, not sure what the difference would be. But we want a something that goes up with the minimum amount of downs possible